# c# insert row into Oracle table

Tags: c#, oracle

I have oracle table named Query_Times. So i create TableAdapter using VS2010, and add insert query to it:

```
INSERT INTO QUERY_TIMES (ID, QRY_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (1, @qry_time)
```

QRY_TIMESTAMP is timestamp(6) data type.

In code i try to execute query like this:

```
QUERY_TIMESTableAdapter tblqry_times = new QUERY_TIMESTableAdapter();
tblqry_times.InsertQryTime(currTime);
```

but i got an error Message=ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.

How to correctly define parameter to use it in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses the `:` parameter prefix (see http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/adonet-command-parameters.html)

Comment: my big fail((. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you use variables like '`:variableName'`. This called bind variable. It improves query performance as execution plan gets reuse. So, if you use bind variables, you have to assign its value as well through you `front-end code`.